# How can I use types from a third party x64 dll in xamlx designer?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, workflow-foundation-4

The problem is that VS2010sp1 is a 32bit app and won't load 64bit assemblies.

I have made custom activities that reference types as InArgument/OutArguments from a 64bit 3rd party dll. (Or more generally, I have designer components that involve types from a 64bit dll that should be placed on a VS hosted WPF designer)

These components cannot be then used in VS xaml/xamlx designers because VS is a 32bit app. How can this limitation be overcome, without asking the supplier to rebuild for AnyCPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. If something is designed to be hosted in a 64 bit application that is what it needs. If your app is 32 bits it can't host that assembly. So your only option is to use two applications and communicate between them. But as you are suggesting you need a WPF component from that assembly there is AFAIK no way to do so.

Comment: Thanks, Maurice (and fellow disciple of the WF doctrine! :-) ) - It's an annoying limitation. Trying to use Qpid AMQP client libraries within custom WF4 activities (and expose their type) - I don't have AnyCPU assemblies available, and don't have time on this project to get 32bit assemblies working. For now, I have to architect things differently.

Comment: The problem isn't that his application is 32bit, it is that Visual Studio is 32bit. Visual Studio can't display activities in the designer that are compiled in x64. You can read the following blog post for information about why Visual Studio is 32bit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx